# UNION query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this two queries.

```
select * from blog_post where isDelete=0 
          and pOrder !=0 order by pOrder asc
select * from blog_post where isDelete=0 
          and pOrder=0 order by postID desc
```

that is working fine.

but when I try to join this two query into `union`,

```
select * from 
    ((select * from blog_post 
               where isDelete=0 and pOrder !=0 
               order by pOrder asc) 
      union all 
     (select * from blog_post 
               where isDelete=0 and pOrder=0 
               order by postID desc )) as tbl1
```

it gives second query's output in ascending order but in query it is in descending order.

Comment: in ur query pOrder and postID are different columns ..?

Comment: Yes its different column

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows.

```
(select * from blog_post where isDelete=0 and pOrder !=0 order by pOrder asc)
UNION
(select * from blog_post where isDelete=0 and pOrder=0 order by postID desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
select * from(select col1,col2,...colN,'1' as sorting from blog_post where isDelete=0 and pOrder !=0 order by pOrder asc UNION All select col1,col2,...colN,'1' as sorting from blog_post where isDelete=0 and pOrder=0 order by postID desc) temp order by sorting asc,if (sorting=1,pOrder,0) asc,if (sorting=2,postID,0) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
select * from blog_post where isDelete=0 and pOrder != 0
UNION ALL
select * from blog_post where isDelete=0 and pOrder = 0
order by  pOrder,postID
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this query by following.

select * from blog_post where isDelete = 0 order by (case pOrder when 0 then (select Max(pOrder) + 1 from blog_post) else pOrder end) asc, postID desc

Thanks for your comment for this question, I was just working on it and above query gave me perfect what I wanted.